# How do I know whether to attach a direct object pronoun to the infinitive?

Tags: pronombres, sintaxis, infinitivo, enclisis

I often struggle to decide what sounds right when I need to use direct object pronouns. [Lessons on these pronouns](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/dopro3.htm) have not been much help because they teach that when using a direct object pronoun it is okay to either leave it on its own or attach it to the infinitive, and "neither method is 'better' than the other".

> Lo quiero ver.
>   Quiero verlo.

In simple examples like this, I can see how both ways sound ok.

However, in longer statements, especially negative ones, I often find myself stumbling if I try to say the version with the pronoun out front. For example, I find the second version much easier to say in this example:

> Juan no lo necesita lavar.
>   Juan no necesita lavarlo.

(If there are [indirect object pronouns](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/iodopro.htm) too, I think I often prefer the second version where everything is attached to the infinitive:)

> No te lo quiero decir.
>   No quiero decírtelo.

I'm not a native speaker, so I might just find one way hard to say and don't have enough exposure to tell what sounds right.

I'd like to know: In what ways are the styles not exactly the same? For example, is one way more common in speech or in writing? Does it vary for the short or the complicated examples? Is there a reason you choose one way or the other (sounds more formal or friendly, makes the point better)?

Comment: I don't dare to give you a proper answer, but mostly they can be used both. When they sound strange one way, is quite likely in a case per case reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Este tipo de pronombres que funcionan como complemento verbal no preposicional se denominan, en general, *pronombres clíticos*. Cuando anteceden al verbo (*me* encanta; *lo* dijo; *se* fue) se llaman *proclíticos* y cuando siguen al verbo (ayúdame, díselo, vete) se llaman *enclíticos*.

La colocación de los pronombres clíticos delante o detrás del verbo no es libre, sino que está sometida a ciertas reglas, que han ido variando con el tiempo. El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas recoge las reglas actuales para la colocación de los clíticos en el español general culto.

A continuación presento de manera resumida y reorganizada las reglas que determinan la correcta (o incorrecta) colocación de los pronombres clíticos; la discusión completa puede encontrarse en el artículo [Pronombres personales átonos](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=pronombres%20personales%20%E1tonos) del *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*.

## Formas simples

### Uso Correcto

1. Los clíticos se anteponen a las formas simples de indicativo:

   > Correcto: «Te lo advierto: me voy».
   >
   > Correcto: «Os lo garantizo».

   En la lengua escrita, sobretodo si se quiere recrear el lenguaje de épocas pasadas, pueden colocarse pospuestos a principio de oración o después de pausa:

   > Permitido con restricciones: «Como si adivinara mi pensamiento, díjome al punto: “La verdad es desnuda”» (RBastos Vigilia [Par. 1992]).
2. Los clíticos se anteponen también a las formas simples del subjuntivo, tanto a las independientes:

   > Correcto: «Ojalá le concedan el premio».
   >
   > Correcto: «Quizá lo consiga».

   como a las que dependen de otro verbo (explícito o implícito):

   > Correcto: «Espero que te lo pienses».
   >
   > Correcto: «Que te vaya bien».
3. Los clíticos se posponen a las formas de imperativo y a las del subjuntivo exhortativo afirmativo:

   > Correcto: «Hazlo».
   >
   > Correcto: «Dígannoslo».
   >
   > Correcto: «Hágase la luz».
4. La anteposición es obligada a las formas del subjuntivo cuando este va en forma negativa o depende de otro verbo (explícito o implícito):

   > Correcto: «No lo hagan».
   >
   > Correcto: «Les ordeno que se callen».
   >
   > Correcto: «Que se vayan ahora mismo».
5. Los clíticos se posponen a las formas simples de infinitivo y de gerundio:

   > Correcto: «Al mirarlo, sonrió».
   >
   > Correcto: «No conseguirás nada regañándome».
6. Si el infinitivo o el gerundio forman parte de una perífrasis verbal, en la mayor parte de los casos los clíticos pueden colocarse también delante del verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis, que es el que aparece en forma personal:

   > Correcto: «Debo hacerlo o también «Lo debo hacer».
   >
   > Correcto: «Tienes que llevárselo o también «Se lo tienes que llevar».
   >
   > Correcto: Vais a arrepentiros o también «Os vais a arrepentir».
   >
   > Correcto: Siguió explicándomelo o también «Me lo siguió explicando».
7. Solo es admisible la agregación de enclíticos a un participio cuando aparece en coordinación con otro y no se repite el auxiliar:

   > Correcto: «Y después de haber adorado a Dios y dádole gracias, se sentaron» (Somers Retrato [Ur. 1990]).

### Uso Incorrecto:

1. No se debe usar la posposición de los clíticos cuando el verbo va en forma negativa:

   > Incorrecto: *«No díjomelo».
   >
   > Correcto: «No me lo dijo».
2. Es vulgar y debe, por lo tanto, evitarse anteponer los clíticos al subjuntivo exhortativo cuando este no depende de otro verbo:

   > Incorrecto: *«¡Se callen, carajo!»
   >
   > Correcto: «!Cállense, carajo!»
3. Es incorrecto anteponer los clíticos cuando el verbo auxiliar de la perífrasis es impersonal:

   > Incorrecto: *«Se lo hay que pedir».
   >
   > Correcto: «Hay que pedírselo».

   o si el verbo en forma no personal es el sujeto oracional pospuesto de verbos como parecer, importar, convenir, etc.:

   > Incorrecto: *«Lo parecía entender».
   >
   > Correcto: «Parecía entenderlo».
   >
   > Incorrecto: *«Lo conviene intentar».
   >
   > Correcto: «Conviene intentarlo».

   Tampoco es normal la anteposición de clíticos con verbos que expresan creencia, temor, deseo, preferencia o conocimiento, como creer, temer, desear, preferir, negar, afirmar, entre otros:

   > Poco natural: «Lo cree haber guardado».
   >
   > Correcto: «Cree haberlo guardado».
   >
   > Poco natural: «Te prefiero ignorar».
   >
   > Correcto: «Prefiero ignorarte».
   >
   > Poco natural: «Lo negó saber».
   >
   > Correcto: «Negó saberlo».
4. El participio no admite con normalidad la agregación de pronombres enclíticos:

   > Incorrecto: *«Había prometídole su apoyo».
   >
   > Correcto: «Le había prometido su apoyo».

   Más forzado aún resulta el uso de enclíticos con participios en función adjetiva que sustituyen a oraciones de relativo:

   > Incorrecto: *«El accidente ocurrídole ayer».
   >
   > Correcto: «El accidente que le ocurrió ayer».

## Formas compuestas

Lo dicho para las formas simples es válido también para las compuestas, teniendo en cuenta que la posposición o anteposición de los pronombres átonos se da siempre con respecto al auxiliar haber, dado que el participio, como norma general, no admite enclíticos.

Comment: Outside of this article, I've *never* seen or heard a sentence like *«Como si adivinara mi pensamiento, díjome al punto: “La verdad es desnuda”» (RBastos Vigilia [Par. 1992])* so that one must be particularly literary. I can also add that placing the direct object after the verb is most natural after questions (I asked a native speaker about this once). So *¿Quieres hacerlo?* is better than *¿Lo quieres hacer?* - although, that said, the latter sentence also looks natural but the meaning is more of confirming the wanting vs. asking if they want to do it at all.

Comment: @KevinK. Yes; the use of *pronombres clíticos* as in "díjome" is almost reserved to literature: in the Bible, for example, there are numerous instances of this kind ("díjome", "díjole", etc.). I agree with the second part of your comment.

Comment: «Como si adivinara mi pensamiento, díjome al punto: “La verdad es desnuda”» is a very nice formed sentence. Obsolete and literary, but beautiful.

Comment: Incorrecto: «¡Se callen, carajo!». Bueno, en España se permitiría por una anécdota famosísima. El 23-f del año 1981 la Guardia Civil irrumpe en el Congreso promoviendo un golpe de estado contra la democracia. Dos diputados no se amilanan ante las armas y se encaran contra los golpistas, uno de ellos es general e intenta imponer su grado sobre el cabecilla que era teniente-coronel. Y entonces Tejero dice una frase inolvidable para los españoles: «Que se sienten, coño» seguido de muchos tiros al techo. Desde entonces «Se callen, carajo» o «Se sienten, coño» se permite y produce alguna sonrisa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta muy completa y útil. Siento que no puedo dar el "botín" a las dos respuestas, pero tuve que decidir.

Answer (score 10):

I guess [@Gonzalo has answered your question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/473/238) from the correct, formal and theoretical point of view.

However, I wish to share my thoughts since I am a native speaker. @KevinK said:

> the latter sentence ["¿Lo quieres hacer?"] also looks natural but the meaning is more of confirming the wanting vs. asking if they want to do it at all

About this, I use to say:

> ¿*Quieres* hacerlo?

when I want to know if **you** want to do it. The emphasis is in the implied subject *you*. I am interested in your inner wishes. *You* are more important than the *it*. I am interested in your which are *your* inner wishes, about how do *you* feel.

But when I ask:

> ¿*Lo* quieres hacer?

I am stressing the "it". May be the "it" is awkward, embarrassing, or even dangerous. So, I want you to reconsider your decision. As a matter of fact, I use this form when I know already your wishes, but I want you to notice about the "it".

In both cases, I emphasize the first word (by increasing a little the volume of the voice, slowing down the velocity, etc).

---

Note: as [hippetrail](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-do-i-know-whether-to-attach-a-direct-object-pronoun-to-the-infinitive#comment1132_608) says, this phenomenon is called [*topicalization* or *fronting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29#Topicalization_.28fronting.29) in linguistics.

Comment: No you're not wrong. This exact phenomenon you describe is called in linguistics either [*topicalization* or *fronting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29#Topicalization_.28fronting.29).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Cuando trato de hablar naturalmente este va a ser muy útil :)

Answer (score 2):

Some additional information not noted in other answers.  One of the reasons that it will feel more natural, in most cases, to attach the object is that in older Spanish, like modern day European Portuguese, object pronouns were not allowed at the beginning of utterances.

Hence, you could not simply say "Lo quiero hacer" because you've started the sentence with *lo*.  Your options would have been *Quiérolo hacer* (incredibly stilted/archaic/hyperformal, or in the north of Spain like Asturias) or *Quiero hacerlo*.

But, if other words were present in front of the pronouns, then it was possible again.  This most especially happened with negative words.  *No lo quiero hacer* should sound a bit more natural than *Lo quiero hacer* (topicalization notwithstanding).

This is, incidentally, why affirmative commands have postpositioned pronouns and negative commands have prepositioned ones.  The *no* acted as what the Portuguese call an *atrator*, pulling the pronouns to the front of the verb.