# Orden de verbo x sujeto x objeto: ¿son equivalentes "bien conocemos nosotros" y "nosotros bien conocemos"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, orden-de-palabras

La siguiente frase fue creada por mí mismo en base a algunos temas que he estado estudiando.

> Bien conocemos nosotros los errores que cometieron nuestros padres.
> Y, si es así, ¿por qué habremos de los repetir?

Tengo dos dudas:

1. Aunque quizás no sea la forma más habitual, ¿se puede utilizar **bien conocemos nosotros** en lugar de **nosostros bien conocemos**?
2. ¿Se puede usar de **los repetir** en lugar de **repetirlos**?

Comment: Off the bat, I think that "nosotros" may be unnecessary unless you want to emphasize that *we* in particular know their mistakes. The comma after "y" looks unnecessary. "Porque" (because) should be "por qué" (why). The object must be enclitic (repetirlos). To me, "habremos de repetirlos" sounds like "why *will* we have to repeat them," so I would think something like "tendríamos que repetirlos" (why should we?). And, of course, there are those who would opt for "nuestros padres y nuestras madres" for a more gender-neutral phrasing, though many grammarians still frown on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful. I think that clarifies all my doubts.

Comment: _los repetir_ es incorrecto, debe decirse _repetirlos_. Recomiendo leer [How do I know whether to attach a direct object pronoun to the infinitive?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/313/1674)

Comment: The sentece is incorrect.  The question "¿Y, si es así, por qué habremos de los repetir?" is not a question. It question just limits to "Y, si es así, ¿por qué habremos de los repetir?. Consider edit this part.

Comment: Yo hice la edición. Gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Se puede utilizar la forma

- "Bien conocemos nosotros los errores de nuestros padres."
- "Nosostros bien conocemos los errores que cometieron nuestros padres"
- "Conocemos bien los errores que cometieron nuestros padres"
- "Nosotros conocemos bien los errores que cometieron nuestros padres"

Ten presente que:

- Sujeto: Nosotros
- Verbo: Conocemos.
- Objeto directo: [los errores que cometieron nuestros padres]
- Complemento circunstancial de modo: bien

2. ¿Se puede usar **habremos de los repetir** en lugar de **habríamos de repetirlos**?

- Sujeto: Nosotros
- Verbo: Habríamos de repetir.

  - Es condicional. Tu conjugación es incorrecta. (*Y, ***si es así***, ¿por qué habremos de los repetir?*)
  - Construcción para denotar obligación: ***Habríamos de + infinitivo***.
- Objeto directo: los errores.

El verbo es una construcción compleja que denota obligación (***haber de + infinitivo***). No puedes poner el pronombre **los** rompiendo la construcción. Por tanto como opciones tienes:

- Y, si es así, ¿por qué ***habríamos de repetirlos***?
- Y, si es así, ¿por qué ***los habríamos de repetir***?
- Y, si es así, ¿por qué ***habríamos de repetir los errores que cometieron nuestros padres***?